# tmux/bash start tmux only if normal shell (intellij)

Tags: bash, environment-variables, tmux, intellij

I have a little problem, I let tmux start in the `.bashrc` but I only want it to start, if the shell is a normal shell inside my terminal emulator.

Now most IDEs have a terminal tab where they launch a shell (in which in my case now) tmux is started. If I close the IDE, tmux is not ended properly, so the session is still running.

This leads to detatched tmux sessions I do not want.

Is there any way, to prevent tmux from being launched in that ocasions (e.g. a environment variable, only set if the shell is launched by a terminal emulator or some way to properly end the session in the IDE (in my case intellij) when closing the IDE)?